# WkhtmlToPDF global javascript variables. Access data in footer

Tags: javascript, wkhtmltopdf

I have to create 1 PDF containing multiple documents grouped like this:

- Doc1 (TypeA)
- Doc2 (TypeB)
- Doc3 (TypeB)
- Doc4 (TypeC)
- Doc5 (TypeC)

On each page footer I need this information:

1. page number / total pages (provided by `page` and `topage` from `window.location.search`
2. page number / total pages of single document
3. document number/documents of same type

**1.** Is provided by `windows.location.search`

**3.** I can set this numbers in `<h1></h1>` before sending htmls to wkhtml. This will be available in `window.location.serach` under `section` or `subsection`

**2.** This is fun part. It would be easy if I would be able to store information in footer javascript. Something like internal counter which I can reset each time section or subsection is changed.

**So question is: how to store variable shared between footers? Is there any other way to achieve what I need?**

Footer per each PDF page:

- Doc1 (TypeA): pdf-page 1/7 | document-page 1/2 | type 1/1
- Doc1 (TypeA): pdf-page 2/7 | document-page 2/2 | type 1/1
- Doc2 (TypeB): pdf-page 3/7 | document-page 1/1 | type 1/2
- Doc3 (TypeB): pdf-page 4/7 | document-page 1/2 | type 2/2
- Doc3 (TypeB): pdf-page 5/7 | document-page 2/2 | type 2/2
- Doc4 (TypeC): pdf-page 6/7 | document-page 1/1 | type 1/2
- Doc5 (TypeC): pdf-page 7/7 | document-page 1/1 | type 2/2

This is almost like creating 5 PDFs and merging them into one.

Answer (score 2):

You could reset the numbering of each section using JS `cookies`. Follow this example: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3708#issuecomment-346701655

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function setSectionCounter() {
        var vars = {};
        var queryStringsFromUrl = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
        for (var queryString in queryStringsFromUrl) {
            if (queryStringsFromUrl.hasOwnProperty(queryString)) {
                var temp = queryStringsFromUrl[queryString].split('=', 2);
                vars[temp[0]] = decodeURI(temp[1]);
            }
        }

        var element = document.getElementById('sectionCounter');

        if (document.cookie.split(';').length === 2) {
          var section = document.cookie.split(';')[0].split('=')[1];

          if (vars.section !== section) {
            document.cookie = 'currentSection=' + vars.section;
            document.cookie = 'startedAt=' + vars.page;
          }

          // startedAt is the page on which a section started
          var startedAt = parseInt(document.cookie.split(';')[1].split('=')[1]);
          element.textContent = vars.page - startedAt + 1;
        } else {
          document.cookie = 'currentSection=' + vars.section;
          document.cookie = 'startedAt=' + vars.page;
          element.textContent = 1;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="setSectionCounter()">
    <p id="sectionCounter"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Disclaimer: This solution will not work for the total number of pages per section, it only provides a counter.

Hope it helps.